# Solutions being called localhost_xxxx in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Pro and I'm finding it irritation when I create a new website the solution gets called localhost_ plus the port number. I can manually amend the solution name.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a setting I can change?